# How to load data only when single page is visible?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-mobile

I have a little **jQuery mobile** website where I want to visualize some data (I did that with D3). The website has **multiple pages** (made with `<div data-role="page" id="...">...</div>`). As I have quite a lot of data to load (json from server), I **only want to load what the user currently sees**. I.e. if he clicks on page 2 (via Button), I only want to load the data necessary for the page 2 (and not all the data for the other 10 pages). I found a couple of jQuery **events** (pageshow, etc.) - but all of them are only catched when the mainpage is created the first time. I also thought about just loading it, when the use clicks a button (link), but what if he directly navigates to the page2?

Any **suggestions** would be really much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: search SO for all questions related to _pagination_, just use an ajax call and pagination, I'd say

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it out:

```
$('#pageTag').bind('pageshow', function() {
   $.ajax({
  url: "getData.php"
   }).done(function( data ) {
  alert( "response from server: " + data);
   });
}
```

The problem here is, that it get's called every time the page is loaded. So, if the user navigates back and fourth, it loads every time... I found some hints [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/page-load-event), but not the solution for my second problem...

Any hints will be appreciated very much. thanks.

Comment: at the moment I am solving this with a flag. If it already loaded, it will not load again... It's not very clean, but works...

Answer (score 2):

I think making use of AJAX is your best bet here. You can keep track of each "page" using # in your url e.g. YOUR_URL#page_2.

If the user navigates straight to that page, it will render the page. Otherwise, if he goes to the home page, it will render #page_1 and not #page_2 or #page_3.. so on and forth.

Hope I understood your question.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I am searching for, thanks. I'll try to find out how to do this...

Comment: As I don't know Ajax... Do you know a good tutorial or link to read? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp is a good place to start.

Comment: if you are looking at jquery, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ has a nice api and maybe if you need more help you could look at http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/01/26/tutorials-round-up-ajax-css-javascript-php-mysql-and-more/

Comment: @AaronLee: please, don't refer to [w3schools](http://w3fools.com/), also: it might be best to use an URI like `URL?page=2`, because a relative anchor might just imply that the entire page should be rendered anyway... @cascaout: us [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) to get started with AJAX, it's a far better reference than crummy W3Schools. The latter having _no authority_ despite what the name might have you believe